# Is "Graduate Of" the same as "Undergraduate Of"?

Tags: adjectives

**If I had completed a bachelor's from Harvard**, would I be able to say I was:

> a graduate of Harvard University

Or does the term "graduate" apply only to those who have completed a master's or doctorate?

Would it more accurate--less ambiguous--to say I was:

> an undergraduate of Harvard University

Or are both terms interchangeable?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Did you check the definitions and uses of *graduate* and *undergraduate* in a dictionary? If so, please [edit] the post to indicate that research and why you are still confused. *Graduate* is not used to mean *graduate student* in the same way that *undergraduate* is used to mean *undergraduate student*.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a *graduate* then you have graduated from Harvard (in this case) regardless of the degree you obtained.

If you are an *undergraduate* it means that you are still a student enrolled in an *undergraduate* program; you have not yet graduated and obtained an *undergraduate* degree.

*Graduates* may have an *undergraduate* degree (a Bachelor's degree) or a *graduate* degree (either a Master's degree or Doctorate degree). A *graduate* student is somebody who's currently enrolled in a *graduate* program.

To make it slightly more confusing, if you are enrolled in a Master's or Doctorate program, you can also be said to be a *postgraduate*, somebody who is enrolled in a *postgraduate* program (even if you haven't actually obtained your *postgraduate* degree yet).

Many universities provide both *undergraduate* and *postgraduate* (or *graduate*) degree programs; others provide only one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a degree granted by a university, especially a first degree, then you are a graduate of that university. You can no longer call yourself an undergraduate. That term is reserved for university students who have not yet taken a first (bachelor's) degree. The terms are not interchangeable.

> **undergraduate** *noun*
>   A university student who has not yet taken a first degree.
>   ‘a group of Oxford undergraduates’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/undergraduate)

Comment: to add a tad more - someone studying for a masters or PHD would generally be called a "graduate student".  I believe the "graduate student" would apply to both a 'masters student' or a 'PHD candidate".  A graduate with a Bachelors Degree may or may not have  gone on to get a ~Graduate Degree~  ?

Comment: I think you mean "not yet completed"

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to say you were an undergraduate. That will give the impression you gave up or were kicked out.
Graduate is the correct term for anyone that has graduated (which is more than completing - you also have to pay all the library fines, fight with the administration, fix their internal mail system, and bang on enough doors until they let you have the piece of paper).